# How do I find out whether a control can accept focus?

Tags: javascript, html

This seems like such a simple question, but I can't find the answer here, or even using the Google. (The first Google result for "javascript can control accept focus" looks perfect, but is a dead link.)

I have a basic dropdown:

```
<select name="ddlScope" id="ddlScope">
<option value="-1"></option>
<option value="1">Global</option>
<option value="2">Public</option>
<option value="3">Private</option>
<option value="5">Admin</option>
</select>
```

When I'm doing validation, I want to set focus to the control if the value is not valid. But it's in a `<tr>` that may or may not be visible. If the `<tr>` isn't visible, the `focus()` method fails:

```
var ddlScope = document.getElementById("ddlScope");
if (ddlScope.value == "0" || ddlScope.value == "-1")
{
    ShowAlert("Please make a valid selection for Scope.");
    ddlScope.focus();
    return false;
}
```

I could check the visibility of the enclosing `<tr>`, but that makes for a messy page-specific hack. Surely there's a way to check whether the control can accept focus, before I attempt to give it focus?

Update: I ended up giving up, and removing the `.focus()` entirely. It's not an interactive enough form that the user would miss it. But I'm still awfully curious how determining "focusability" would be accomplished.

Comment: Why don't you know that the element is hidden? You shouldn't need to check the DOM, this _statefulness_ should be in your model.

Comment: You don't say what "method fails" means, but why don't you just handle the error (handle the return code or catch the exception or check if the item you set focus to got the focus) if you're getting an error.  Then you can set focus and if that "fails", then you can use an alternate strategy.  This seems more foolproof than trying to figure ahead of time whether setting focus "might" fail or not.

Comment: Why would you validate a hidden element?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: The field is in a collapsible section that may have been collapsed by the user, so I don't directly control its visibility. Also: I don't think my co-workers, during code review, would look kindly upon relying on trapping for an _expected_ error. (In fact, I've railed against that technique in the VB6 code that our web app is replacing.)